# Need to trigger plugin on pre-validation when activitymimeattachments are created with incoming email

Tags: email, plugins, dynamics-crm, email-attachments, dataverse

**Requirement**

I have a requirement, where I have to make some changes to activitymimeattachment's body, before it is created.

**Problem**

I made a plugin with the required business logic and registered it on Create Pre-Operation, but for some reason, it kept ignoring my changes. Everything worked fine and the code did not break. It just ignored my changes. So, I tried changing my step to Pre-Validation and it started working as expected.

The problem is, pre-validation step is only triggering, when attachment is created by someone on the email record manually. When an email comes into the system from outside with attachments, only Pre-Operation and Post-Operation steps are triggering on Activitymimeattachment. The Pre-Validation step does not get triggered.

My problem can be solved by either of the following:

1. If there is a way to make these changes work in Pre-Operation step.
2. If there is another step on another primary entity, where I can intercept Activitymimeattachment record before it is created.

Following is the code. The content, which is being traced on the last line writes the expected result. For some reason, it just does not reflect on the attachment. The same code would work on Pre-Validation.

```
if (target.Contains("body"))
{
    SharepointService.Initialize(provider);

    //Upload attachment to SharePoint
    var uploadedDocument = SharepointService.UploadAttachment(target);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadedDocument.ID))
    {
        string document = Serializer.SerializeObject<UploadedDocument>(uploadedDocument);

        //Replace Base64 body of attachment with document ID from SharePoint
        target["body"] = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(document));
        provider.Trace((string)target["body"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the plugin code in your question to check why preoperation is not working. Ideally if prevalidation works, pre operation is supposed to work.

Comment: @Harinarayanan I have added the code. Please have a look.

Comment: Everything seems to be in order. Unless sharepoint upload fails the code should execute fine. Do you get an error? Have u tried to debug the plugin to see if everything executes?

Comment: As you can see from the code. I traced the body of the target after it is set with my required content. It traces just fine and no exception is thrown at all. I saw a couple of other questions as well where people reported that some activity type entities are also showing this behavior, but none of the questions had a solution. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: That is a strange behaviour though. Did you try post operation? The logic should work just fine in post operation too.

Comment: Yes and that would work fine. But the problem is, it will take another update call after creation, which is unnecessary in this case. Ideally, it should be done in pre-operation and if necessary, pre-validation. For n attachments we will have n additional update calls. I am not sure of the load in production. If there will be high number of attachments, this can cause trouble.
I can also not run it asynchronously to keep the user experience fluid, because if there are multiple attachments, and email is immediately sent, I would not be sure whether logic was run for all of them or not.

Comment: unless there is an infinite loop with update to attachments, there will not be a signigicant degrade to user experience. As I'm not aware of the complete picture of what this logic does in the system, I cant be fore sure what impact it has on changing to post operation.  Onething i cant understand is are you trying to upload the attachment to  Sharepoint? if yes then why would you want to upload attachment in realtime when user sends email?